# Using saveLocation: "file" always causes the photo orientation to be landscape (instead of portrait)

Tags: trigger.io, forge

One issue I found (or I haven't used it correctly) is that using saveLocation: "file" always causes the photo orientation to be landscape during file upload.

(I'd like the photos to be in portrait orientation instead).

I tried to force the orientation to portrait using the config.json setting of:

```
"orientations": {
    "default": "portrait",
    "iphone": "portrait",      
},
```

but it didn't fix the issue.

My invocation of getImages is like:

```
forge.file.getImage({
    source: "camera",
    saveLocation: "file",
    width: 300,
    height: 300
}, function (file) { ... }
);
```

If I remove saveLocation: "file", then the uploaded photos are in portrait orientation.

Answer (score 1):

this is due to Trigger.io not using EXIF data when reading in photos: we get rotation information when reading from the gallery, but should do a better job when reading from a file.

**Update**: this was fixed in v.1.4.27 of the Trigger.io platform. See http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/release-notes.html#v1-4-27.

When displaying the images returned from `file.getImage`, we automatically handle orientation.

When uploading the images to your server, using `forge.request.ajax`, there are two possibilities. Either:

- image size constraints have been specified and we apply a scale and rotate transform to the image
- no image size constraints are specified and we pass through the raw image data

Therefore, if there is Exif orientation data in the uploaded image, you can use it in any post-processing you want to do. If there's no Exif data, either the device isn't capable of providing that data or we've already pre-rotated the image to be the right way up.